# JTableModel rows wrong added

Tags: java, swing

this is my TableModel:

```
public class ScheduledRecordsTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private String[] headers = {"Interpret", "Titel"};
    private List<ScheduledRecord> scheduledRecords;

    public ScheduledRecordsTableModel(List<ScheduledRecord> recordsList) {
        super();
        this.scheduledRecords = recordsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return scheduledRecords.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return headers[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        ScheduledRecord r = scheduledRecords.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return r.getActor();
            case 1:
                return r.getTitle();
            default:
                return null;
        }


    }

    public void addRow(ScheduledRecord r) {
        ScheduledRecord toAdd = null;
        for (Iterator<ScheduledRecord> recordIterator = scheduledRecords.iterator(); recordIterator.hasNext(); ) {
            ScheduledRecord record = recordIterator.next();
            if (record.equals(r)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Scheduled Record " + r.toString() + " already exists");
            } else {
                toAdd = record;
            }
        }
        scheduledRecords.add(toAdd);
    }

    public void removeRow(ScheduledRecord r) {
        scheduledRecords.remove(r);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public ScheduledRecord getScheduledRecordFromIndex(int index) {
        return scheduledRecords.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

here is how i add new entries:

```
private void saveScheduledRecord() {
    if (checkInputValues()) {
        WebradioPlayer.addScheduledRecord(new ScheduledRecord(titleField.getText(), artistField.getText()));
        this.dispose();
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter a valid artist/title", "Invalid input", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("artist or title input did not match the specifications");
    }
}
```

and here the addScheduledRecord method:

```
public static synchronized boolean addScheduledRecord(ScheduledRecord record) {
    RecorderController.getInstance().addScheduledRecord(record);
    Gui.getInstance().getRecorderTab().getScheduledRecordsWindow().getTable().getScheduledRecordsTableModel().addRow(record);
    Gui.getInstance().getRecorderTab().getScheduledRecordsWindow().getTable().getScheduledRecordsTableModel().fireTableDataChanged();
    databaseConnector.addScheduledRecord(record);
    return true;
}
```

If i add an entry, the 'previous' one is added to the table, however if i close the table and open it again it is all correct. RecorderController just holds an own list for other purposes (this list is modified in another way)
Does anyone see my mistake here?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Check this: if (record.equals(r))  works only if ScheduledRecord implements proper hashCode and equals methods - or they are both the exact same instance in memory.

Comment: fireTableDataChanged(); for addRow also?

Comment: List passed in constructor is being changed outside the Table Model in some other code not shown here?List<ScheduledRecord> recordsList

Comment: @Teddy yes, they do implement a proper equals method. i did the event firing because i thought it may help. i will check the list right now

Comment: The List is changed nowhere outside. it comes directly from the database and is never changed.

Comment: addRow method has a bug. toAdd will be null if the first row is being added.

Comment: quick-fixed with an if statement:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix the addRow method (no need to iterate, while there is a contains method):

```
public void addRow(ScheduledRecord r) {
    if (scheduledRecords.contains(r)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Scheduled Record " + r.toString() + " already exists");
    }
    scheduledRecords.add(r);
}
```

Comment: But using tableDataChanged is just fine for me because i don't know the position of the new row in my table?

Comment: You are right... tableDataChanged  should cover all changes.

Comment: Yes, but also in debugging i don't know why the last entrie is shown 'double'. the adding woks correct, because if i reopen the window all is fine

Comment: If you reopen the window, your List is built externally? Further rows are added with addRow method which has a bug?

Comment: it is like this : new TableModel(ListFromDatabase assigned to private list), addRow adds to private list